# Is there a tabbed SSH client with connection management for Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'm looking for a tabbed SSH client on Ubuntu that supports managing the details of saved connections. An ideal solution would be (like) Putty with tab support.

HotSSH supports tabbing, but I would like more Putty-like options, such as giving saved connections custom names, being able to change details of existing connections (e.g. port; with HotSSH this currently becomes a new session in your history), initiating a session without saving it, deleting a saved session.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of my colleagues use and are quite satisfied with [PAC Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/). They especially like the cluster connections which send multiple machines the same keystrokes.

Comment: This looks very promising. Do you know if it supports using the ssh authentication agent instead of specifying the passphrase for your private key? I couldn't find this option.

Comment: @arjan: My colleagues says that it's supported. Actually it calls the external `ssh` executable and supports everything that the command line `ssh` supports (but it does not have GUI for every setting).

Comment: Looks like something was off the first time I tried. Having loaded my private key with ssh-add and just leaving the passphrase empty works now.

Comment: I've been using PAC for years and it's very nice. However it completly crashed my local session several times so I'm looking for something else.

Comment: I had problems using PAC Manager in Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10. It would just crash. While I used PAC Manager for years before then, maybe it is old for Ubu* 18 and newer? According to its SourceForge page its last update was about 3 years ago. https://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/

Answer (score 4):

I have tried PAC, but I found that [Gnome Connection Manager](http://kuthulu.com/gcm/) worked better for me.

PAC seemed to have too many buttons and too many options. GCM had a cleaner look while providing similar features to Putty CM.